correlation test - assumptions and the test choice
I have to run correlation analysis between A and B and between C and B. A and B are continuous variables, B is dichotomous (0,1). I wanted to run Pearson correlation for A and B correlation but my data is not normally distributed (Shapiro Wilk = .000) and histogram indicate slightly not normal data especially for B variable. For the second analysis I planned point biserial analysis but variable B is not normally distributed for each category of C, no outliers, and Levene test is significant p= .018. I wanted to run Spearman rho analysis but I am not sure if the assumptions are not violated. My C variable (0,1) and B variable dont exhibit monotonic relationship ? on scaterplot i have dots forming two horizontal lines.  i dont know how to upload picture of it.

You write "A and B are continuous variables, B is dichotomous (0,1)." This seems in error: did you mean "A and C are continuous"? Also, you say that B is "slightly non-normal"; byt B is dichotomous? It can never be normal. Can you please correct/clarify the question?
